# PublicClientApplication cctor doesn't work on windows phone 8.1 (System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a simple way to connect to a microsoft account in my app using Microsoft Graph (in a c# project).

I followed the sample for UWP (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) and everything works fine on UWP and Windows 8.1, however I am stuck on Windows Phone 8.1 at initializing a PublicClientApplication.

```
private static PublicClientApplication m_identityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication("clientId", /*-optional-"authorityLink"*/);
```

The PublicClientApplication constructor doesn't seem to work regardless if a put as arguments one/two random strings, a valid app/client id, with or without an authority string.
I have Microsoft.Identity.Client as reference in my project and have

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
```

added in my .cs file. 
I also tried using the latest (1.1.4) or an older (1.1.0) Microsoft.Identity.Client package, nothing changed.

m_identityClientApp remains null and so my app crashes with a System.NullReferenceException exception.

I am out of ideas... :(

Comment: *"`m_identityClientApp` remains null"* despite that fact that it's clearly initialized? *"PublicClientApplication constructor doesn't seem to work"*: constructors don't ever return `null`, so either it works or it crashes, or it's not being called.

Comment: I'm pretty clueless regarding Win Phones, but msdn docs say 'Class to be used for native applications (Desktop/UWP/iOS/Android)'. Does this include Win Phone? Sorry for maybe newbish question/hint ;)

Comment: @spender I mentioned that the app does crash, it crashes when I try to call a method from that .cs file where I am trying to initialize the m_identityClientApp.

Comment: @spender I phrased it like that ("it remains null") because I also tried initializing m_identityClientApp  from the beginning, where it's declared, and then put a random breackpoint at the start of the first method called and when it was hit, m_identityClientApp appeared to be null. :)

Comment: @nilsK to be honest I am not completely sure, but since it's in the Microsoft.Identity.Client package and that package can be found for wp8.1 too I assumed it can work.